# MySQL.data config File - Visual Basic 2008

Tags: sql, mysql, visual-studio-2008

I use mysql.data in my visual basic 2008 project. When I build my app and look into the RELEASE folder, I need the .exe.config file to run my app orless it would not work. How would I incorporate this into my application so that I don't need it when I debug my app?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You just add an app.config (or web.config for web apps) to your project, leave the build action to none, and all the defaults, and it will be copied and renamed to YourApp.exe.config (if it's an exe project) and deployed automatically whenever you build and there's changes, to the Release/Bin folder or whatever the target bin folder is at the time.